# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a mock: java.lang.Class on PowerMock and EasyMock

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock, easymock

I have a test case using PowerMock to test on static method from Math, as

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest( { Math.class })
public class Test{
    @Test
        public void test2(){
            PowerMockito.mockStatic(Math.class);
            EasyMock.expect(Math.abs(-123)).andReturn(1);
            EasyMock.replay(Math.class);
            long returns = Math.abs(-123);
            EasyMock.verify(Math.class);
            org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(1,returns);
        }
}
```

My pom.xml looks as

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>${mockito.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
            <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

And I got error as

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a mock: java.lang.Class
    at org.easymock.internal.MocksControl.getControl(MocksControl.java:175)
    at org.easymock.EasyMock.getControl(EasyMock.java:2130)
    at org.easymock.EasyMock.replay(EasyMock.java:2032)
```

This is the first time I'm using PowerMock, I just want to try to test static method, and I Choose Java Math class to test. I think I have done all the parts in the instructions from https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockStatic

What's wrong with my test case?

Comment: Maybe it's because `EasyMock` should be `PowerMockito` in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using EasyMock, I use mockito to replace it, code as

```
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(Math.class);
    Mockito.when(Math.abs(-123)).thenReturn(1);
    int returns = Math.abs(-123);
```

This code is working fine for me in Java 7, but in java 8, it fails

Answer (score 3):

I face this issue and I resolve it by using `PowerMock.replay(StaticClass.class)`

In your case, all you have to do is replace `EasyMock.replay(Math.class);` with `PowerMock.replay(Math.class);` since you are already used "PowerMock".

Comment: I have resolved this issue when I use `org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock.replay;` `org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock.verify;` instead of `org.easymock.EasyMock.replay;` `org.easymock.EasyMock.verify;`